# How to extract a certain part of code with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.9

I'm working on a private project, and I've a question about Beautiful Soup. I'm using python 3.9.2 and Beautiful Soup 4.9.3.
My html code is:
`style="transform-origin:50% 50%;transform:rotate(382deg)`
I want to get the part: *382deg*. Does anyone now how to do this using Beautiful Soup?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the desired value, You can apply regex technique

```
style = soup.select_one('style:-soup-contains("rotate")').get('style')

v = re.search(r'rotate\((.*)\)',style).group(1)
```

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
style = '''
<td style="transform-origin:50% 50%;transform:rotate(382deg)"> </td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(style,'lxml')

txt = soup.select_one('td')
t=txt.get('style')
v = re.search(r'rotate\((.*)\)',t).group(1)
print(v)
```

**Output:**

```
382deg
```